# MSQL unique constraint check only onward insert records Not already existing records

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint

The table already has duplicates entries. I want to create a unique constraint in MQSL DB without deleting the existing duplicates. If any duplicate entries coming onwards then it will show an error. Given blow queries not working in MYSQL.

```
ALTER TABLE presence
ADD CONSTRAINT present uniqueness UNIQUE (employee_id,roll_number) where id >10000;

or 
ALTER TABLE presence
ADD CONSTRAINT present uniqueness UNIQUE (employee_id,roll_number) where id <> (343,34534,34534)
```

Do we have something like that solution in SQL?

Comment: Why not simply fix the already bad data?

Answer (score 2):

Add an additional column to the table that indicates the existing values.

Set it to `NULL` for the existing values.  And give it a constant value, say `1`, for the new rows.  Then create a unique index or constraint on this column:

```
alter table t add constraint unique (employee_id, is_old)
```

Actually, I realize that you probably don't want duplicates with singleton old values and new values.  That is just an issue of setting the value to `NULL` only for *duplicates* in the history.  So, one row would have a constant value (say `1`) in the historical data.

MySQL allows duplicate values on `NULL`, which is why this works.